# Export / Import index with elasticdump not working

Tags: elasticsearch

I have tried to export/import index with elasticdump.
I have two servers, on server A an elasticsearch version 5.4 and on server B an elasticsearch version 7.10.
When I tried to use elasticdump (2.2), I have tried this on server A:

```
elasticdump --input="http://xx.xxx.xxx.xx:9200/myindex" --output="http://xx.xxx.xxx.xx:9200/myindex" --type=data --searchBody '{"query": { "match_all": {} }, "stored_fields": ["*"], "_source": true }'
```

find below the final lines:

```
Tue, 26 Jan 2021 08:19:20 GMT | got 100 objects from source elasticsearch (offset: 4900)
Tue, 26 Jan 2021 08:19:20 GMT | sent 100 objects to destination elasticsearch, wrote 0
Tue, 26 Jan 2021 08:19:20 GMT | got 100 objects from source elasticsearch (offset: 5000)
Tue, 26 Jan 2021 08:19:20 GMT | sent 100 objects to destination elasticsearch, wrote 0
Tue, 26 Jan 2021 08:19:20 GMT | got 100 objects from source elasticsearch (offset: 5100)
Tue, 26 Jan 2021 08:19:20 GMT | sent 100 objects to destination elasticsearch, wrote 0
Tue, 26 Jan 2021 08:19:20 GMT | got 32 objects from source elasticsearch (offset: 5200)
Tue, 26 Jan 2021 08:19:20 GMT | sent 32 objects to destination elasticsearch, wrote 0
Tue, 26 Jan 2021 08:19:20 GMT | got 0 objects from source elasticsearch (offset: 5232)
Tue, 26 Jan 2021 08:19:20 GMT | Total Writes: 0
Tue, 26 Jan 2021 08:19:20 GMT | dump complete
```

There is no data written on the other side.
I have tried to write the dump (json format) on filesystem and import it, same result.

Can you please help ?
Thanks

David

Comment: What happens when you temporarily save the output with `--output=backup.json`? Does the data get saved?

Comment: It's work, the backup file is created

Comment: Do you have access to server B's logs?

Comment: yes, I saw this in elasticsearch.log but this is not when I have tried to use elasticdump

Comment: `[2021-01-26T10:42:41,276][WARN ][o.e.t.TcpTransport       ] [xxx] SSL/TLS request received but SSL/TLS is not enabled on this node, got (16,3,1,1), [Netty4TcpChannel{localAddress=/xxx:9300, remoteAddress=/xx.xx.xx.xx:53422}], closing connection`

Comment: I also tried to import with a json file :

Comment: Is that all the debug spits out?

Comment: Sorry for the format : `Tue, 26 Jan 2021 10:46:15 GMT | starting dump
Tue, 26 Jan 2021 10:46:15 GMT | got 1 objects from source file (offset: 0)
Tue, 26 Jan 2021 10:46:15 GMT [debug] | thisUrl: http://localhost:9200/wasnd/_bulk, payload.body: "some data"
Tue, 26 Jan 2021 10:46:15 GMT | Error Emitted => Cannot read property 'body' of undefined
Tue, 26 Jan 2021 10:46:15 GMT | Total Writes: 0
Tue, 26 Jan 2021 10:46:15 GMT | dump ended with error (set phase)  => TypeError: Cannot read property 'body' of undefined`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I used _reindex :

```
POST _reindex
{
  "source": {
    "remote": {
      "host": "https://REMOTE_ELASTICSEARCH_ENDPOINT:PORT",
      "username": "USER",
      "password": "PASSWORD"
    },
    "index": "INDEX_NAME",
    "query": {
      "match_all": {}
    }
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "INDEX_NAME"
  }
}
```

It works perfectly.
Thanks a lot

David